# ReactJS: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm tried to figure out How can I have these two buttons the Login and Sign up that will be toggling the Login and Sign up box back in forward.

I couldn't figure out.... Does anyone can solve this?

this is my code. I'd like to call "selected-controller" method from div item. But then, Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../components/pages/Forms/MainScreen";
import Dropdown from "../components//pages/dropdowns/dropdowns"; 
import hamburger from "../images/menu.svg";

class Navigation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isExpanded: false
        };
    }

    handleToggle(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          isExpanded: !prevState.isExpanded, // negate the previous expanded state
        }));
      }

    render() {

        const { isExpanded } = this.state;

      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="NavbarContainer">
                  <div className="mobilecontainer LeftNav">
                      <h2 className="BrandName LeftNav mobileboxmenu inline FarRight">Kommonplaces</h2>
                      <div className="hamburger inlinev" >
                          <img 
                            onClick={e => this.handleToggle(e)}
                            alt="menubtn" 
                            src={hamburger}
                          />
                      </div>
                  </div>


                  <ul className={`NavBar collapsed ${isExpanded ? "is-expanded" : ""}`}>
                        <Dropdown/>    
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Host Your Space</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">About Us</Link></li>
                        <li className="RightNav"><Link to="/">Contact Us</Link></li>
                        <div className="btnflexright">
                        <div
                            className={"controller " + (this.state.isLoginOpen
                            ? "selected-controller"
                            : "")}
                            onClick={this
                            .showLoginBox
                            .bind(this)}>
                            Login
                        </div>

                        <div
                            className={"controller " + (this.state.isRegisterOpen
                            ? "selected-controller"
                            : "")}
                            onClick={this
                            .showRegisterBox
                            .bind(this)}>
                            Sign up
                        </div>
                        </div>
                  </ul>
               </div>
         </Router>
      );
    }
}

  export default Navigation;
```

**This is the main screen where the login and Sign form will go:**

```
import React from 'react';
import RegisterBox from '../Forms/Register'
import LoginBox from '../Forms/Register'

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoginOpen: true,
      isRegisterOpen: false
    };
  }

  showLoginBox() {
    this.setState({isLoginOpen: true, isRegisterOpen: false});
  }

  showRegisterBox() {
    this.setState({isRegisterOpen: true, isLoginOpen: false});
  }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="root-container">
                {this.state.isLoginOpen && <LoginBox/>}
                {this.state.isRegisterOpen && <RegisterBox/>}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Login and Sign up Form are the same but in two different files Login.js and Register,js I will show the code for that one now.**

```
//Login Box 
import React from 'react';

class LoginBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

      render() {
          return (
            <div>
                <div className="formContent modal-main">
                    <h2>Welcome Back <span>Brandon!</span></h2>
                    <form>                         
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="email" 
                            placeholder="Email Address" 
                        />

                        <input 
                            name="password" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Password" 

                        />

                        <div className="passContent">
                            <div className="checkingPass">
                                <input 
                                    className="inline" 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    name="check" 
                                    value="Remember Password"
                                />
                                <span 
                                    className="inline">
                                    Remember Password
                                </span>
                            </div>
                                <p 
                                    className="passFont">
                                    Forgot Password
                                </p>
                        </div>

                        <input 
                            className="formmbtn" 
                            type="button" 
                            name="button" 
                            alue="Login"
                        />

                        <div 
                            className="social-media-button">
                            <input 
                                className="clearbtn" 
                                type="button" 
                                name="button" 
                                value="Sign in with Facebook"
                            />

                            <div 
                                className="divider"
                            />

                            <input 
                                className="clearbtn" 
                                type="button" 
                                name="button" 
                                value="Sign in with Facebook"
                            />

                        </div>

                        <p 
                            className="passFont">
                            Don't have an account? 
                            <span>Sign up</span>
                        </p>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>               
          )
      }
  }

  export default LoginBox;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `Navigation` doesn't have the functions `showRegisterBox` and `showLoginBox`, so `this.showRegisterBox` is `undefined` (that's why you get the `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` error when you do `this.showRegisterBox.bind()` on the `Navigation` Component.

**Possible solutions:**

If those functions aren't defined in the `Navigation` component, then you should probably pass them as props when you instantiate `Navigation`. That's the usual way a component communicates with it's parent component.

So if for example you were to use your `Navigation` component in `App` (which is where those functions are defined), you would do:

```
<Navigation showRegisterBox={this.showRegisterBox.bind(this)} showLoginBox={this.showLoginBox.bind(this)}/>
```

Then in `Navigation` you use them like such:

```
onClick={this.props.showRegisterBox}
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but don't you still need to bind `showRegisterBox` and `showLoginBox` to the `App` component?

Comment: @khuynh you're correct, I'll edit my answer, thank you!

Comment: @Ismael Padilla So, the first code will go inside the `Navigation.js` Thank you so much for explain to me in detail I need this

Comment: `<Navigation showRegisterBox={this.showRegisterBox.bind(this)} showLoginBox={this.showLoginBox.bind(this)}/>` I put this in file home.js that where all my living on the home page is that the right way